# installing python .egg in google colab

Tags: python, installation, google-colaboratory

I have a problem with google colaboratory, specifically with installing a python egg.
I need package called morfeusz2 http://morfeusz.sgjp.pl/ but the only way to use it is to download egg from their site and install it via easy_install. Unfortunately i can't install it on google colab. Python version on colab is 3.6.9 and I'm installing a morfeusz for 3.6 so it should work fine.So my question is how to install it or what should I do to use morfeusz in google colab?

Answer (score 0):

Actually downloading egg is not the only way to do it. Here is working code for Colab:

```
!wget -O - http://download.sgjp.pl/apt/sgjp.gpg.key|sudo apt-key add -
!sudo apt-add-repository http://download.sgjp.pl/apt/ubuntu
!sudo apt update
!sudo apt install morfeusz2 python3-morfeusz2
```